# Rigify IK to FK Snap, IK loses Twist

Tags: rigify, inverse-kinematics

i'm using a superlimb: paw for the foreleg of this horse.  i have created a lying down pose with the FK rig.

i snapped the IK rig to it, and that worked fine.  however, when i switch from FK to IK... the upper leg twists.  or untwists.

https://recordit.co/32VRUY7Vds
http://g.recordit.co/32VRUY7Vds.gif

either way... i don't know what to do to compensate for this or fix it.  is there a way, or is the rigify IK not meant to do this?

i found that the tweak ball for that bone will twist it... but somehow it doesn't twist it exactly back to where it should go?  i am brand new to rigify, and totally lost.

thanks, guys!

Comment: I think the IK/FK snap can be imperfect, especially at extreme poses and your pose is quite extreme. I notice that you use 2.7x. Have you tired 2.8? Rigify received some updates recently. I tested a pose similar to yours in 2.8 and I get no twisting.

Comment: i opened the file in 2.8, but the rigify python no longer worked.  i'll look for a conversion method, or i can just start over in 2.8.  thanks for looking!

Comment: If you still have your meta rig you may be able to re-generate the rig and Append your Action. Not sure if it will work, but it could.